# if (string or string or string) not in variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm trying to get an `if` statement to work, but for some reasons it doesn't work. It should be very simple.

Assume that the string `title = "Today I went to the sea"`

My code is:

```
 if "Today" or "sea" in title:
      print 1

 if "Today" or "sea" not in title:
      print 1
```

Both specifications result in 1.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
if "Today" in title or "sea" in title:
  print 1
```

(similar for the second piece of code).

How `if` statements work is they evaluate expressions joined by words like `or` or `and`.  So your statement was reading like this:

```
if ("Today") or ("sea" in title):
  print 1
```

Because `"Today"` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) it was always evaluating to `true`

Answer (score 1):

I guarantee this has been answered somewhere else on SO and you should first check there before asking a new question.

The issue with your code:

```
if 'Today' or 'sea' in title:
```

This checks if 'today' is True or  if 'sea' is in title, 'today' == type(string) therefore it exists/True, 'sea' in title == True and evaluates to True, `if 'today' or 'sea' not in title` 'today' is again type(string) and therefore exists/True and 'sea' not in title = False, and again evaluates to True. How to fix this! `if 'Today' in title or 'Sea' in title:` or below to make it easily modable! Good Luck!

```
strings_to_compare = ['Today', 'sea', 'etc...']

for i in strings_to_compare:
    if i in title:
        print i
```